# Two Web User Controls inside a page: lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, page-lifecycle

I have an aspx page and have two (or more) controls in the page. If i have two controls, how do I know which control's `Page_Load` will execute first or whose `Page_Init` will be executed first? And is there a way to control that? Meaning, can i somehow tell the page to execute one before the other? 
Thanks

PS:By controls i mean web user controls (.ascx)

Comment: You seem to be confused (or maybe I am) a control does not have a page load the page does. Are you asking about controlling what control is initialized first?

Comment: I am talking about `web user control` ofcourse. Sorry if it was confusing

Answer (score 1):

To find out turn on page tracing by using the page directive `Trace="true"`.

To make trace output show up, then you need to add `Trace.Warn` statements to the events of the objects you are interested in, such as:

In `Page_Load` of the .aspx page:

```
Trace.Warn("MyPage.aspx - Inside Page_Load event");
```

Here is the documentation for [How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I am only getting the trace of .aspx page and nothing for .ascx page.

Comment: OMG, I am out of it today, sorry you will need to add `Trace.Warn` statements to your events of interest. Updated answer.